# Java-OOP I keep on getting this strange output

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, computer-science, bluej

I am currently taking Computer Science at school and I am a bit stuck on my lab. 
The directions are listed below and we are required to use an OOP.
The problem is that my output that I get is super strange and I really don't know what is going on.

The output that I get after running the file `DiscountRunner.java` (code listed below) is:

```
Enter the original bill amount :: 4000
Discount@1d1be4e
```

Why do I keep on getting the `Discount@1d1be4e` part?

```
/**==================================================================================================
 * Objective :         This lab was designed to teach you how to use if statements.
 * Lab Description :   Determine the amount of discount a person should receive.   
 *                     If the bill is more than 2000, then the person should receive a 15% discount.  
 *                     If the bill is 2000 dollars or less, the person does not receive a 
 *                     discount of any kind.
 ===================================================================================================*/


import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiscountRunner
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    out.print("Enter the original bill amount :: ");
    int amt = keyboard.nextInt();

    int Discount;

    Discount bill=new Discount();
    bill.getDiscountedBill();

    System.out.println(bill);
    //instantiate a new Discount object called "bill"
    //print the output of bill.getDiscountedBill() with amt as the parameter

}
}
```

That is file one.

Here is file two.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Discount
{
//instance variables and constructors could be used, but are not really needed

int amt;
int bill;

//getDiscountedBill() will return final amount of the bill
//          if the bill is >2000, the bill receives a 15% discount



   public int getDiscountedBill()
   {
       if ( amt>2000)
           bill=amt*(int).85;
       if ( amt<=2000)
           bill=amt*1;


       return bill;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some little mistakes of Type conversions and some in receiving value from method.
Find below the working code

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiscountRunner
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Discount bill=new Discount();
    out.print("Enter the original bill amount :: ");
    bill.amt = keyboard.nextInt();

    int discount;


    discount=bill.getDiscountedBill();

    System.out.println(discount);
    //instantiate a new Discount object called "bill"
    //print the output of bill.getDiscountedBill() with amt as the parameter

}

}

import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Discount
{
//instance variables and constructors could be used, but are not really needed

int amt;
int bill;

//getDiscountedBill() will return final amount of the bill
//          if the bill is >2000, the bill receives a 15% discount



   public int getDiscountedBill()
   {
       if ( amt>2000)
           **bill=(int)(amt*.85);**
       if ( amt<=2000)
           bill=amt*1;

       return bill;
   }
}
```

Let me know if you are not getting something.
Accept the answer if it solves your Problem.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println()` method will try to convert a object to a string before printing it out. In order to do this it will normally call `Object.toString()` method. The default implementation of said method is to generate a string containing the object type concatenated with the in-memory address of the object. This is what is happening to you.

To fix it you need to provide a `toString()` implementation to the `Discount` method.

Answer (score 1):

You get this because of this line:

```
System.out.println(bill);
```

You are printing the object which calls the default [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) implementation of `Discount` (inherited from `Object`). You can overwrite `toString()` in `Discount` to get a custom representation but I guess you just want to remove this `System.out` statement there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't override the `toString()` method in the `Discount` class which is inherited by the Java class `Object`. This causes the output you listed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass a Object to System.out.println it executes its toString method, Default implementation of toString prints ClassName with its hashCode. you can override toString method. add below code snnipet to your Discount Class and it will run as per your expectation

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Bill Amount After Discount is " + bill ;
}
```